# C++ delete pointer array - double free or corruption

Tags: c++

This is just a test project to understand how inheritance works. Cat is a subclass of Mammal, which again is a subclass of Animal.

```
int main()
{
    Cat* cat1 = new Cat("nosy grey", 1.0d, 3);
    Cat* cat2 = new Cat("purply green", 2.0d, 4);

    Cat* cats[] = {cat1, cat2};

    delete [] cats;
 }
```

So I can't really do that, because then I get this.

```
*** Error in `/home/max/git/info-2-ss/Blatt3/Aufgabe2/main.exe': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fff55fd7b10 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80a46)[0x7f3a07452a46]
/home/max/git/info-2-ss/Blatt3/Aufgabe2/main.exe[0x40178e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f3a073f3ea5]
/home/max/git/info-2-ss/Blatt3/Aufgabe2/main.exe[0x400d39]
```

I output when my constructors and destructors are called, so when my Cats get created I get something like this:

```
Called ctor of Animal with age: 3
Called ctor of Mammal with hairLength: 1
Called ctor of Cat with eyecolor: nosy grey
```

When I change my code a bit so it reads:

```
delete [] *cats;
```

then I would've expected that my dtors get called like this for every Cat:

```
Called dtor of Cat
Called dtor of Mammal 
Called dtor of Animal
```

instead I get this single line:

```
Called dtor of Cat
```

Summary:
How can I effectively delete my arrays, so that all my dtors get called?

Comment: You really should read about pointers and dynamic allocation first. `cats[]` is allocated on stack, you cant `delete` it. Instead you should iterate over it and use `delete` to  its every element.

Comment: Don't use `delete` unless you used `new`. You have stack allocation, let it clean up itself. Consider learning about `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` - it will be easier to learn than manual memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `delete[]` on array only if you got **this array** from `new ...[]`! Like this:

```
Cat * cats = new Cat[2];
delete [] cats;
```

The above would be correct. But note that, of course, in this case you cannot pass arguments to constructor.

*Now, your case*. You didn't create array with `new`, so you **should not delete the array itself** (it is on stack, not in heap). That's why `delete[] cats` crashes. *Next*, `*cats` treats array as a pointer and dereferenses it, i.e. returns the item this pointer points to. For array it is the beginning of the array: **`*cats` is the same as `cats[0]`**. That's why only first item gets deleted in your second try.

Finally, the answer: instead of all this, **delete *each item* individually**. For your simple case:

```
delete cat1;
delete cat2;
```

Or, more generally:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(cats)/sizeof(cats[0]); ++i) {
    delete cats[i];
}
```

Here `sizeof(cats)/sizeof(cats[0])` is a simple trick to get the number of items in array by dividing its size by the size of an element.

By this you free the memory where each of your `Cat` objects is placed. If you are worried about the memory where your *array of pointers* lays — it is on stack, which means that it will be freed automaticaly on return from the function.

Answer (score 8):

This

```
Cat* cats[] = {cat1, cat2};
```

Creates an array of pointers to cats with auto storage! You didn't allocate the array with `new[]`, so you shouldn't release it with `delete[]`.

Comment: hm, I think about this question. How can I check, if a pointer to array is a pointer to `auto-storage` array?

Comment: @loldop, there is not a reliable way as far as I'm aware. That's why so much effort goes towards implementing various ownership semantics. The basic rule of thumb is: only free what you yourself allocated, and if you need to own something either document the fact explicitly or clone it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i = 0; i < len(cats)/sizeof(Cat); i++) {
  delete cats[i];
}
```

`delete[] cats` would have worked only if you'd created `cats` using `cats = new Cat[num_cats]`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to delete the array itself, just its elements. Your array `cats` is on the stack, as you didn't create it using `new` or `malloc`.

So all you have to do is

```
delete cat1;
delete cat2;
```

or equivalently

```
delete cats[0];
delete cats[1];
```